# Is it possible to render tile-based web mapping projects in any other projection than web mercator?

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping

Web-mapping technology has to a large degree adopted the web-mercator projection as the standard projection for displaying geographic objects with interactive map-clients. This is due to many factors including the mathematical simplicity of the cylindrical projection which enables fast tile creation, the relatively good preservation of shapes and angles which attracted seafarers to the projection presented by mercator in 1569, and of course it´s adoption by google, bing, ArcGIS Online which further strengthens it´s position as a standard web-mapping projection as in order to create slippy maps, one has to conform to the base-map projection as given.

I am however creating a geoportal for a region of the world which has absolutely no interest in displaying other regions of the globe. The map will also never be used for sea navigation as it is completely landlocked. Having reliable map resolutions which do not change with latitude is also significant due the necessity of presenting formal map objects(e.g Planning documents) with a given scale which is a massive disadvantage of the web mercator projection.

My question is: Is it at all possible to render tile-based web mapping projects in any other projection than web mercator and what are the implications regarding performance and interoperability with other WMS services if this possible? This would be advantageous for regional web mapping projects in order to offer added functionality which is often missing e.g reliable distance measurement over relatively large areas and also support of human understandable resolutions and therefore scales instead of zoom-levels giving users the ability to render maps at 1:1000, 1:10,000 etc.

Comment: Yes of course it's possible, just use gdal2tiles it's really easy. Interoperability, not sure, but I don't see that it's really relevant. Mercator is a terrible projection, it's just a simple compromise for the entire globe in one plane. There's also longlat, Cylindrical Equal Area, Peters, and none are "very good" because they apply to the whole world, but they work in a narrow context for a purpose.

Comment: read the WMST spec http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326 - GWC will allow you to provide custom gridsets